# Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: abort(Error: WebAssembly.Module doesn't parse at byte xxx

Tags: c++, build, webassembly, emscripten, emsdk

I got a .wasm file with emscripten. It works on websites on desktop, but it doesn't work at mobile browsers and I got this error. I'm using;

-Emscripten 3.0.1
-OpenCV 4.5.3

How can I fix this problem?